read newly added records from apache iceberg
we have pipelines that are continuously writing to iceberg. In the snapshot table we can see summary for each snapshot id. The summary shows number of added/deleted /total records for each snapshot id . Is there anyway to read only newly added records in the latest snapshot.
i tried using method. But looks like it only support append mode
    spark.read
  .format("iceberg")
  .option("start-snapshot-id", "10963874102873")
  .option("end-snapshot-id", "63874143573109")
  .load("path/to/table")

